# prevent Asp.NET button from submitting form

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, paypal

So, I have a Paypal form that worked wonders. However, I now need to add a coupon field, where someone can enter a code, and get a reduction based on whatever the backend replies.

This all works wonderfully, but I've ran into an issue when adding the option to know *before checking out* whether your code is valid or not. Currently, my form (once simplified) looks like this :

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"
    id="payPalForm" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCode" />
    <asp:Button Text="Validate" OnClick="ValidateDiscount" runat="server" />
    <asp:Label ID="txtDesc" runat="server" />

    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Pay up!" />

    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />
    ...
</form>
```

With the backend having the function :

```
protected void ValidateDiscount(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.txtDesc.Text = "fetch from database using: " + txtCode.Text;
}
```

My issue is that wheneve I click on the Validate button, the form is submitted and I end up on the Paypal website. I used Jquery at first with preventDefault(), but that actually prevents my server-side function from firing. I've also tried putting a standard `<button>` or `<input type='button'>` tag instead, but I couldn't get it to fire my server-side function.

Is there any way to have the Validate button not submit the form, or should I just remove the action from the form and manually submit the form when clicking on the submit button?

Comment: Your form will post to paypal because that's the action that you set up for it to do. You have a number of options. You might try redirecting to paypal from the ValidateDiscount function in c# when you find the discount to be valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have set your form action to post to PayPal.

This is the action:

```
action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"
```

Here is where you have it in you form tag:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"
id="payPalForm" runat="server">
```

Remove this from your form tag and it should postback to your application.

Comment: Oh... I didn't actually know that form's action prevented postback '-' TIL

Comment: Yes, it can catch you out. The W3C website has more information: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp.